# Restrictions in UML class diagram

Tags: uml

How do I implement a restriction in a UML class diagram; lets say I want a user to agree with the terms and conditions before he can be able to register.

Comment: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-core.html#comment

Comment: @xmojmr or did you mean http://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html :-)

Comment: @ThomasKilian I meant `note` but constraint sounds better :-)

Answer (score 4):

Modelling in a UML isn't limited to using just one type of diagrams and I can hardly imagine a functional model having only class diagrams for instance.

What you describe is basically a behaviour while class diagram is describing a static part of the system. Instead of putting this information on a class diagram you should consider one of behavioural diagrams with activity diagram and sequence diagram as two top choices.

As for class diagram itself you can show some level of dependency by constrains. But this is only dependency on entities level (e.g. in Account class the attribute termsAndConditionsAcceptanse:Boolean might have a constraint that it is not null and only True value is allowed). Note however that it doesn't show any precedence of actions or steps of the registration. That can be modelled only with behavioural diagrams which I definitely recommend you to solve this problem.

Just for completeness of answer purposes. The constraint is shown in curly brackets either inline after an attribute or in a separate compartment in a class entity or as a note linked to a class or other kind of entity to which the constraint applies.
As UML specification says the constraint should have this notation:

```
<constraint> ::= ‘{‘ [ <name> ‘:’ ] <boolean-expression> ‘ }’
```

See 7.6 of UML specification for details.